# Netbeans RCP with default IDE's editor

Tags: java, netbeans, rcp, netbeans-platform

I am developing a **Netbeans RCP application**, where one of my `TopComponent` is in `Editor` Mode.

I want the default Editor window's customized `textArea` from Netbeans IDE (with all line number and syntax formatting) in my `TopComponent` 
,instead of a container where i can add other components.

(e.g)

```
TopComponent componenet = nwe TopComponent(); 
//code to add the default IDE's editor in to the component. ?
```

Is it possible to do it? Does netbeans allow it?

Comment: Yes, that's definitely possible and allowed. But there are a lot of default Editors in NetBeans IDE. Do you want to create a java editor or a html editor or just all?

Comment: @PaL I want the C/C++ editor..